# Django default settings module errors

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

My immediate goal is to port my (first) Django project to Google App Engine. It is running fine in Django’s runserver. However, in the GAE SDK I get nothing but blank white pages. I have looked at the [Django `settings` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/), the [`django-admin` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/), and the [GAE Cloud-SQL Django documenation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django).
I am on Windows 8.1 with Django 1.6.1 and Python 2.7 and a MySQL 5.5 backend. I have the GAE SDK 1.8.9.

One of the messages I got was that the SDK didn’t work with Django 1.6.1 so I set the version to ‘latest’.

When I ran `django-admin.py syncdb --settings=mysite.settings` from within the directory, I got no error messages from Django but still got the blank pages and the same error message from the SDK as before:

```
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Then I ran `django-admin.py syncdb --settings=[absolute path] mysite.settings`. This time I got this from the command line:

```
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'C:\Users…settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): Import by filename is not supported.
```

The SDK still gives the same error. Then I tried putting the path directly into environmental variables myself, in `PYTHONPATH` between Django and App Engine, but I still get the same errors, so now I am turning to you. What do I do now?